# React Dynamic CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, width

I am trying to create a rectangle that is "6.25%" times the width returned from a function for a calendar view. The rectangles will represent the number of hours of the appointment and must shrink proportionally so they line up with the hours on the axis if the screen is resized.
This is what I want to do, but this does not work.

```
class Appointment extends React.Component {
  getWidth(appt){
    return Math.abs((new Date(appt.end_at)-(new Date(appt.start_at))))/3600000
 }
  render () {
    var style = {
        width:this.getWidth(this.props.appointment) *'6.25%',
        height:'30px',
        background:'blue',
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="rectangle" style={style}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can't multiply by a string. Get the value first, then create the string:

```
var width = this.getWidth(this.props.appointment) * 0.0625;
var style = {
    width:`${width}px`,
    height:'30px',
    background:'blue',
};
```

You didn't specify the units you were using, so I assumed `px`. Also, if you're unfamiliar with template strings, this is some good documentation on them: https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-template-strings